# Javascript, автоперевод таймера обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот страничка [www.sflower.co.il/?show_timer](https://www.sflower.co.il/?show_timer) с таймером обратного отсчета на базе jquery.countdown.

Задача состоит в следующем. Нужно каждую неделю автоматически переводить таймер на неделю вперед.

Сейчас у меня это реализовано следующим образом. Страница делает ajax-запрос на сервер и получает ответ в виде конечной даты.

То есть на уровне php все работает как положено. Проблема в том, что на запрос уходит время и ресурсы.

Можно ли сделать все подсчеты только на JavaScript?

Вот код инициализации каунтера:

```js
var $countdown = $(".countdown");

if($countdown.length){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_counter_time",
        dataType: "json",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(data){
        $countdown.countdown(data.countdown_end, function(event){
            $(this).html(event.strftime("<span>%D<span>" + $countdown.data("day-tt4") +
            "</span></span><span>%H<span>" + $countdown.data("day-tt3") +
            "</span></span><span>%M<span>" + $countdown.data("day-tt2") +
            "</span></span><span>%S<span>" + $countdown.data("day-tt1") +
            "</span></span>"));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Привяжитесь к дню недели( пускай будет пятница ) и на клиенте отображайте сколько осталось до пятницы. Тут правда могут быть проблемы с разными часовыми поясами, но возможно, для вас это не проблема

Comment: Это не совсем подходит. Например если нужно будет переводить каждых 30 дней. Акции у нас бывают разные ))

Comment: Тогда либо привязываться у какому-либо числу(к примеру, последний день месяца), либо обращаться к серверу + закэшировать вычисления, либо каждый раз сидеть и хардкодить даты на клиенте